# Why a key's encoding is "int" in Redis but its type is "string" in lua script?

Tags: redis

When I use lua script in redis, I met a problem that I cannot understand.

For example, I have a key "test" and its value is 2 and its encoding is int:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set test 2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> object encoding test
"int"
```

but when I use the key in lua script, its type in lua becomes string:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval "local a = redis.call('get', 'test'); return type(a);" 0
"string"
```

Why does redis convert int encoding key to string in lua?

Comment: Because the value type of `SET` command is **STRING**, although its internal encoding is **INT**.

Comment: @for_stack make the comment into an answer and I'll upvote it

Comment: @for_stack Thanks. Well I think most value types of redis commands are string, so I would always get string type in lua.

Comment: @ItamarHaber OK, I'll do it. B.T.W long time no see :)

Comment: @nethibernate There're also other types, check my answer for detail.

Comment: @for_stack yeah, been buried with tasks and didn't have time to spend here. Now that RedisConf19 is over I can get back to normality :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value type of `SET` command is STRING, although its internal encoding is INT (for memory and performance efficient).

In fact, based on [Redis protocol](https://redis.io/topics/protocol), there're 5 kinds of return types. You can check [the manual](https://redis.io/commands) for the return type of each command. Also check the [conversion between Lua and Redis data types](https://redis.io/commands/eval#conversion-between-lua-and-redis-data-types).